# Deserializing Json dictionary obj to display multiple values

Tags: javascript, json, asp.net-mvc, dictionary

I have a view with a modal pop-up that displays "parameters" or rather data from a Dictionary being passed to the front end. With my current JS, it appears my function will only deserializing one key and value at a time. However, I need to edit the function so that It can deserialize more than one key and value, if the dictionary is passing in more than one key and value..

Below is my code. If you want to know more about the back end please let me know.

Controller is returning:

`var parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();`

```
return Json(parameters, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

To reiterate, parameters is a Dictionary that can have either one key/value OR it could hold multiple key/value pairs.

JS:

```
   $("button[name='paramsBtn']").click(function () {
    /* Grabs ID from col selected */
    var $col = $(this).closest('.row').find('.requestId');
    var jobRequestId = $col.data('id');

     $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("JobPollerParameters", "Tools")',
         data: { "jobRequestId": jobRequestId},
         success: function (results) {

            $modal = $('#paramsModal');
            $modal.modal("show");

             var arr = results;
             //loop through arr created from dictionary to grab key(s)
             for (var key in arr) {
                 if (arr.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                     var myKey = key;
                 }
             }

             var name = myKey;
             var value = results[myKey];

            $('#modalName').text(name);
             $('#modalMessage').text(value);
        }
    });
});
```

Here is the modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="paramsModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header modal-header-primary">
                <a class="btn btn-xs btn-primary pull-right" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></a>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="modalTitleText">Job Parameters</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="list-group">
                    <div class="row list-group-item list-group-item-heading container divTableHeading" style="width:inherit; margin-bottom:0px;">
                        <div class="col-md-6 font-weight-bold"> Parameter: </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6 font-weight-bold"> Value: </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row list-group-item container" style="width:inherit;">
                        <div class="col-md-6 text-break" id="modalName"></div>
                        <div class="col-md-6 text-break" id="modalMessage"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

This line is confusing:

```
var myKey = key;
```

After the loop completes, `myKey` will be equal to the last *index* in your array, so `2` if `results` had length 3.

So, `name` will equal `2` and `value` will be equal to the last element in `results`

Maybe you're looking for something like this, since `results` is {string, string}:

```
// sample results array from server
var arr = ["val1", "val2", "val3"];
var displayString = "";
for (var key in arr) {
  if (arr.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    displayString += arr[key] + ","; // note, there will be a trailing comma
  }
}
console.log(displayString);
```

Comment: This is a good idea, except I can't use just a single string because I have to set the html elements modalName of the modal to the name and modalMessage to the value. I am displaying them in a grid view.

Comment: @Jacked_Nerd Then you might need a way to identify said multiple elements or dynamically create & insert within the loop. Can you edit your post to include the grid view markup, if applicable?

Comment: @Jacked_Nerd can you specify _where_ in the markup these multiple values are supposed to go? I don't see anything like a grid.

Comment: id="modalName" and id="modalMessage", I guess you could say it's not a grid per say but rather a table made from divs

Comment: @Jacked_Nerd So how do you identify the DOM elements where this needs to be inserted?

Comment: $('#modalName').text(name);
                 $('#modalMessage').text(value);

Answer (score 1):

See the comments below, essentially you arent doing all of the work inside the loop thus your function appears to produce 1 variable (the last one in the dictionary)

```
 $("button[name='paramsBtn']").click(function () {
/* Grabs ID from col selected */
var $col = $(this).closest('.row').find('.requestId');
var jobRequestId = $col.data('id');

 $.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("JobPollerParameters", "Tools")',
     data: { "jobRequestId": jobRequestId},
     success: function (results) {

        $modal = $('#paramsModal');
        $modal.modal("show");

         var arr = results;
         //loop through arr created from dictionary to grab key(s)
         for (var key in arr) {
             if (arr.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                 var myKey = key;
             }
         }
        //Move these variables inside the loop. you are setting them once
        //they are in essence being set to the last value in the dictionary
         var name = myKey;
         var value = results[myKey];
         $('#modalName').text(name);
         $('#modalMessage').text(value);
    }
});
```

});